# Von Neumann algebras are $C^*$-algebras

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

A von Neumann algebra is defined as a *-algebra which is closed w.r.t. the strong operator topology and a $C^*$-algebra as *-algebra with the property $||A||^2=||A^*A||$.

It was said that every von Neumann algebra is a $C^*$-algebra. I tried to show that every von Neumann algebra fulfils the $C^*$ property. I can not get any further and don't know how to use that the von Neumann algebra is closed. Do you have tips?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of a concrete $C^*$-algebra?\

Comment: $C^*$-algebras can be identitied (by Gelfand-Naimark) theorem with norm closed $*$-subalgebras of $B(H),$ the algebra of all bounded linear  operators on a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Aweygan unfortunately not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A von Neumann algebra $M$  lives in some $B(H)$. The C$^*$ relation $$\|T\|^2=\|T^*T\|$$ holds in $B(H)$. So all you need to check is that $M$ is norm closed; and this comes for free since $M$ is closed in a weaker topology than the norm topology.